# while using domain name it shows not found but with IP it works

Tags: servlets, dns, web

while using domain name it shows not found but with IP it works 
I'm using servlets in the code
if i use domain name along with 8080 port and servlet name it works. can anyone please help here

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Please provide more details, so that others can help you.

Comment: website name is http://www.annahockeyleague.com/ if i try this most of the time it is showing "Not Found" error and sometimes it is showing the site but with ip it works fine